# is (n+1)! in the order of (n!)? can you show me a proof?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, computer-science

What about (n-1)!?

Also if you could show me a proof that would help me understand better.

I'm stuck on this one.

Comment: What's "in the order of"? Can you formally define it?

Comment: Big o notation ex O(n)

Comment: Write down the formula you want to prove. Loose terminology and hand-waving ain't gonna cut it. "ex. O(n)"? Nope, neither function is O(n).

Answer (score 3):

To show that (n+1)! is in O(n!) you have to show that there is a constant c so that for all big enough n (n > n0) the inequality

```
(n+1)! < c n!
```

holds. However since (n+1)! = (n+1) n! this simplifies to

```
n+1 < c
```

which clearly does not hold since c is a constant and n can be arbitrarily large.

On the other hand, (n-1)! is in O(n!). The proof is left as an exercise.

Comment: Well, (n-1)! is not a O(n!), but rather o(n!) a little o of n!.

Comment: @ArtemBarger actually it is both. Did you mix up O with Theta?

Answer (score 3):

> (n+1)! = n! * (n+1)

```
O((n+1)*n!) = O(nn!+n!) = O(2(nn!)) = O(n*n!) > O(n!)
```

> (n-1)! = n! * n<sup>-1</sup>

```
O(n-1)! = O(n!/n) < O(n!)
```

Answer (score 2):

I wasnt formally introduced to algorithmic complexity so take what I write with a grain of salt

That said, we know **n^3** is way worse than **n**, right?

Well, since **(n + 1)! = (n - 1)! * n * (n + 1)**

Comparing **(n + 1)! to (n - 1)!** is like comparing **n** to **n^3**

Sorry, I dont have proof but expanding the factorial as above should lead to it